# IIS express combined with Visual Studio community 2015 is very slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, windows-10, iis-express, vs-community-edition

After Visual studio as been installed, doing some tests works at the begining, but at one point, it becomes very slow to the point that the site does not open any more on the developper machine.

A while ago, the files would even beupdated at some point. This is very bizard !

A search did not provided any responses that was able to fix the problem. Any one knows of any known issues ?

If the community edition does not work so good, maybe its not even worth it to move the commercial edition, but to change the developpement technology :P

We can't even find where to get paid support from Microsft...

hank you for the help.

Some informations:
- Visual Studio Community Edition 2015
- Windows 10
- Default IIS Express instalation
- the free default edition de SQL Server.
- asp.net mvc application

Comment: How much Ram do you have on the developer machine running all of this? I recommend 8GB...

Comment: About 16 G. When running the Visual studio in safe mode (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Devenv.exe /SafeModea), IIs is faster... This is wired, because everything is default installation, what kind of extra is put in first default installation that would make everything slow :P...

Comment: It didn't try to add Microsoft search or indexer did it? When you look at Task Manager, is something else running? That would make it slow and eat up a lot of resources until it finishes.

Comment: What would be the process name, would you know ? The omputer is running a video and other programms that working fine. In fact, the first time, even taught it take a while to load, the IIS works. At one point, its just stop working by showing busy (after a while of visual studio of being opened).

Comment: There was also another problem, don't know if its realated, we had pages that are not updated after modifications in Visual Studio.

Comment: when IIS runs a website, it caches it to the framework temp internet files folder and executes it from there. so if the updates are not showing, you can manually delete the files in the folder C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files (note the version folder may be different for your app) you may have to use the dos command IISRESET or stop the website to release the files to be deleted. Don't worry about them, when the site is browsed, it recreates the temp files.